# Comparison of wireless communication technologies: bluetooth vs wifi

Tags: wireless, low-power

I would like to build a simple battery-powered board with temperature and humidity sensors. It should be able to be placed in different rooms of an appartment, and I want to be able to read the values remotely. Eventually I would like to equip all rooms with such board.

I haven't chosen any hardware yet, but I was thinking to connect the sensor(s) with a low-powered microcontroller, and some wireless interface. But considering the somewhat low distance (not more than 10m), the likely presence of wall, I am hesitating on the technology I should use for the wireless communication.

I considered the following technologies

- WiFi,
- Bluetooth.

**Could anyone summarise the pros and cons of those three technologies?** Or point me to a good review, which would help me choose the best for my needs?

<sub>Of course, if I am missing a very crucial technology, do not hesitate to point it out. Radio RF?</sub>

PS. I know that there are commercially available products for exactly such needs, but I would like to do it myself, for the experience it would bring me, and also because of possible extensions I could implement.

Comment: If you could use an already-designed product, [here's](http://www.amazon.com/Ambient-Weather-WS-07-8-Channel-Thermo-Hygrometer/dp/B00BWUOVE8) one for example...

Comment: @bitsmack, indeed. But I would like to do it, for the sake of doing it and learning from the experience. Plus, I now realise I forgot to mention it, I eventually would like to have some in each room of said appartment.

Comment: Very good :)  I am a strong supporter of "doing it for the sake of doing it and learning from the experience"!

Comment: I'm sorry but I think this question is too broad and too open to opinion. "Radio (RF)" is a generic name and wifi and bluetooth are both radios so there are other problems with this question too.

Comment: @Andyaka, too broad, I can't say I understand why. Opinion-based, this is why I asked for pros and cons. Not the best. I had the feeling that it would be good to have such questions here. I may be wrong though. Maybe I should remove the radio point, to avoid that problem, but if they are all radio-based, their use, functions and so on differ.

Comment: If someone comes around, the following blog-post covers Bluetooth, WiFi, Zigbee, Symphony Link, Cellular, XMMP, Sigfox, RFID and Neul.  https://hackernoon.com/9-important-iot-protocols-a-developer-should-know-8541d0af9670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wi-Fi** is a IEEE 802.11 standard:

Pros:

- it is IP based communication
- you don't need build a gateway (I don't mean the router gateway) to transfer the information to the Internet.
- years of proven stack
- Strong security algorithms (AES-256, WPA2, etc.)
- Allows secure tunnels like TLS

Cons:

- Higher power consumption: It is probably not a good choice for a battery powered application unless you put your devices to sleep mode and wake up time to time to do measurements.
- WiFi stack is a heavy stack, it requires a better processor power to handle it (again cost and power)
- Higher cost
- WiFi uses beacon based communication, it constantly radiates (power consideration)
- It is majorly designed for an infrastructured mode, the nodes needs to be in the range of the AP in order to transfer your data. Ad-hoc mode is not well supported

**Bluetooth**: I am not much experienced on Bluetooth, the blueetooth's advantage would be that you can develop an application that you can use connect your phone directly to the devices to control. As I know, bluetooth is for peer to peer communication.

I would go for another standard under the same family of IEEE 802.15.4 **ZigBee**.

Pros:

- Low power
- Light stack
- Application layer compatibility (home automation stack should include what you are looking for)
- Beamless communication (no periodic signals)
- low cost¨
- well supported ad-hoc multi-hop toplogy
- Small packets, less overhead
- Security (AES-128)

Cons:

- You need a gateway to translate internet packets to ZigBee

You can use SoC solution that has ZigBee stack (RF core) + MCU, or you can use a MCU and attack a ZigBee module to run your application

All wireless standards are based on Radio Frequency (RF) waves, I don't know what standard you meant with the RF.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Zigbee - this is basically what it is designed for. Bluetooth has very short range (won't work between rooms) and WIFI uses quite a lot of power comparatively (you'll need a bigger battery). Zigbee is designed to be somewhere in-between and also has the capability to create mesh networks to extend the range.